# Running CodeQL Action always looks for the latest CLI version

Tags: github-actions, codeql

I have a CodeQL CLI bundle (v2.13.5) stored on an on-prem Artifactory repository. I want to fetch this, store it using the tool-cache action and then run the CodeQL action on GitHub Actions.

I have the following code to fetch the bundle which works fine:

```
const artifactoryUrl = `https://example.com/repository_name/CodeQL_2.13.5/codeql-bundle-linux64.tar.gz`;

async function run() {
  const codeQLDirectory = tc.find("CodeQL", "2.13.5");

  if (!codeQLDirectory) {
    let userId = process.env["USER_ID"];
    let pass = process.env["PWD"];
    let authentication = `${userId}:${pass}`;
    let encodedAuthentication = btoa(authentication);

    const downloadPath = await tc.downloadTool(
      artifactoryUrl,
      undefined,
      `Basic ${encodedAuthentication}`,
    );
    const extractedFolder = await tc.extractTar(
      downloadPath,
      "codeql-bundle-linux64",
    );
    const cachedPath = await tc.cacheDir(
      extractedFolder,
      "CodeQL",
      "2.13.5",
      "x64",
    );
    core.addPath(cachedPath);
  }
}
```

I then call the CodeQL action with the following:

```
- name: 'CodeQL init'
  uses: GitHub/codeql-action/init@v2
  with:
    ram: 5120
    queries: security-extended
```

When running this on GitHub I see the following in the debug logs:

```
Setup CodeQL tools
  ##[debug]Attempting to obtain CodeQL tools. CLI version: 2.16.3, bundle tag name: unknown, URL: unspecified.
  ##[debug]isExplicit: 2.16.3
  ##[debug]explicit? true
  ##[debug]checking cache: /home/runner/_work/_tool/CodeQL/2.16.3/x64
  ##[debug]not found
  ##[debug]Didn't find a version of the CodeQL tools in the toolcache with a version number exactly matching 2.16.3.
  ##[debug]isExplicit: 2.13.5
  ##[debug]explicit? true
  ##[debug]Found the following versions of the CodeQL tools in the toolcache: ["2.13.5"].
  ##[debug]Didn't find any versions of the CodeQL tools starting with 2.16.3 in the toolcache. Trying next fallback method.
  ##[debug]Fetching CodeQL CLI version and CodeQL bundle tag name information for releases of the CodeQL tools.
  Error: HttpError: Not Found
  Error: Unable to download and extract CodeQL CLI
  Error: Unable to download and extract CodeQL CLI
```

CodeQL seems to check for the latest version (2.16.3 at the time of writing), Check the tool cache, recognize that 2.13.5 is there but ignore it.
Is there a way to specify a version to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the log references in the [source code](https://github.com/github/codeql-action/blob/905ae4af531685eaee37e94f46845bf4c420dc62/src/setup-codeql.ts#L387), seems like the `cliVersion` variable is evaluated to `2.16.3` and also it is trying to look for the exact same version [here](https://github.com/github/codeql-action/blob/905ae4af531685eaee37e94f46845bf4c420dc62/src/setup-codeql.ts#L359) in the toolcache.

How about you specify the exact codeql cli version in the action itself using `tools` parameter? Looking at the [code](https://github.com/github/codeql-action/blob/905ae4af531685eaee37e94f46845bf4c420dc62/src/setup-codeql.ts#L323-L330), following might make the action look for your desired toolcache version:

```yaml
- name: Initialize CodeQL
  uses: github/codeql-action/init@v3.22.12
  with:
    languages: swift
    queries: security-and-quality
    tools: https://github.com/github/codeql-action/releases/download/codeql-bundle-v2.13.5/codeql-bundle-linux64.tar.gz
```

Comment: This would not help as given URL, it would try to download the bundle from that URL. I'm not looking for that. We have the bundle stored on an Artifactory repository.

Comment: @Ben Have you tried this approach? Although we are specifying the URL, looking at the source code, I am hoping that it will take up the bundle stored in the toolcache itself, instead of downloading it from URL

Comment: Apologies for my previous judgement. I had tried it when I commented, I had just assumed that you missed the Artifactory piece of my question. I can confirm that this worked fine. Given this URL, it recognizes the version to use and fetches it from tool-cache rather than the Internet.